# How to retrieve data based on a dropdown option in laravel livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

**Before you devote my question Please here me out I know this question is asked before but still.**

I Have a table inside my database called:`delivery_fees`[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE8yO.png)
it has 3 columns `destination`,`domicile`and `stopdesk`

- `destination` is the destination
- `domicile` is the shipping amount for home delivery
- `stopdesk` is the shipping amount for the post office

*I have a query that retrieve all destinations*:

```
$destination = DB::table('delivery_fees')->select('destination')->pluck('destination');
```

*I display it on a select option dropdown menu on my view like this:*

```
<select id="wilaya" wire:model="wil" class="hidden block w-full dropdown-toggle flex items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100
         bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300" onchange="closeFunction()">
        @foreach ($destination as $items)
        <option value="{{ $items }}">{{ $items }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
```

*my goal here is when  user choses a `destination` from the option menu I want to retrieve the related value of `domicile` and `stopdesk` I tried query builder inside my component  like this:*

```
$fees = DB::table('delivery_fees')->select('stopdesk', 'domicile')->where('destination','like',$destination)->get();
```

*it throws Back and error of:***`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number`**

**Side Note**
*when I `dd($destination)` I get a collection of an array for all table value*

Please Help

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error **"SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number"** occurs because you're using the `whereLike` method with the `$destination` variable, which is a collection of destinations, not a single destination value. The `whereLike` method expects a single value to compare against.

To fix this issue, you can modify your query to use the `whereIn` method, which is specifically designed to compare against a collection of values. Here's the updated query:

```php
$fees = DB::table('delivery_fees')->select('stopdesk', 'domicile')
    ->whereIn('destination', $destination)
    ->get();
```

This query will select the `stopdesk` and `domicile` columns for all destinations that match the values in the `$destination` collection.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you trying t fetch the shipping fees based on the Selected destination from the dropdown menuu.
you Should try this:

```
use Livewire\Component;
class YourLivewireComponent extends Component
{
    public $wil;
    public $fees = [];

    public function updatedWil()
    {
        $this->fees = DB::table('delivery_fees')
            ->select('stopdesk', 'domicile')
            ->where('destination', $this->wil)
            ->first();
    }

//other methods goes there as well
}


    <div>
        <select id="wilaya" wire:model="wil" class="hidden block w-full dropdown-toggle flex items-center justify-between rounded-lg border border-jacarta-100 bg-white py-3 px-3 dark:border-jacarta-600 dark:bg-jacarta-700 dark:text-jacarta-300" onchange="closeFunction()">
            @foreach ($destination as $items)
                <option value="{{ $items }}">{{ $items }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select> 
    @if (!empty($fees))
            <p>Domicile Fee: {{ $fees->domicile }}</p>
            <p>Stopdesk Fee: {{ $fees->stopdesk }}</p>
        @endif
    </div>
```

Comment: dd($this->fees);  is returning a collection with stopdesk value and domicile how do I display it on a view ?!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).